# Start a service in background which does gets destroyed as in Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-service

I am building a chat app using firebase . I want to show notification for new messages when the app is in background/foreground/terminated . I tried to show it using background service but it gets killed everytime app is destroyed. I know it can be done using FCM but i don't want to use it . It can also be done using foreground service but i don't want that strict notification .
I explored various blogs and i came to know this happens because it runs in same process and to create another process it get complex from Oreo and higher versions.
I also come to know JobService but it minimum periodic time is 15 minutes and if implemented will lose the real time notification nature.

How it can be implemented as in WhatsApp ?
If you see the setting of WhatsApp you will see that ***1 Process and 1 Service*** message keeps showing indicating that **MessageService** is still running which means that it can be done using background service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come to know that WhatsApp is also using FCM kind of thing with high priority to show notification.
It simply syncs the changes in database when data message is recieved using FCM.
This data message can be send using either firebase GUI or trusted environment like admin-sdk ..

I used the later one to send data message using admin-sdk from my server.

I have used APIs with device token of user as data message to send a POST request to my server which sends notification as data message to receiver device to trigger syncing .
Once Syncing is finished , i have send notification accordingly.

Comment: How did you 'come to know'? Any links?

Comment: Regarding working of FCM it is given in documentation and regarding whatsapp i came to know from stackoverflow only